# Fetch with Vite and Qwik using SSR not working behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, vite, qwik

I have trouble working with Vite and Qwik behind a corporate proxy.

I am following the documentation and have this simple code

```js
import { component$ } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import { routeLoader$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-city';
    
export const useDadJoke = routeLoader$(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
    });
    return (await response.json()) as {
        id: string,
        status: number,
        joke: string
    };
});
    
export default component$(() => {
    const dadJokeSignal = useDadJoke();
    return <section class="section bright">
      <p>{dadJokeSignal.value.joke}</p>
    </section>;
});
```

It works properly on my mobile network but as soon as I connect to my corporate network (with a proxy in place), the `fetch` returns an `ECONNREFUSED` response.

I've set `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables to the proper proxy url but Vite seems to ignore that.
I've also tried to change the `proxy` variable in `vite.config.ts`, but from my understanding it is a reverse-proxy and won't do what I am trying to achieve. Anyway it seems like the property is ignored or I misconfigured it.

```js
proxy: {
  '*': {
    target: 'my_proxy_url',
    changeOrigin: false, // I've tried with true too, without success
    proxyTimeout: 1000 * 60
  }
}
```

Any idea how to use Vite & Qwik with the proxy?

Thanks for your help.